# Python issue summing dict into list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary (with multiple objects) I am trying to create a list that sums some of the values for each object. So far I have:

```
import csv,os,re

#numpy.corrcoef(list1, list2)[0, 1]
input_dict = csv.DictReader(open("./MCPlayerData/AllPlayerData2.csv")) 
npi_scores=[]
for person in input_dict:
    #print person
    i=0
    for key in person:
        if re.match(r'npi[0-9]+', key):
            #print key,'=',person[key] #returns npi0=1,npi1=3,npi3=2,etc
            try:
                i+=person[key]
                #print(person[key])
            except TypeError:
                i="NA" #returns NA because one of the values wasnt filled out with an integer
                break
    npi_scores.append(i)
    break
print npi_scores #returns sum of npi scores for one person
print('DONE')
```

When I run this code I get `NA` based on the first element. Which is what I would expect if the value wasnt an integer, but all are definitely integers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

convert person[key] to integer  `int(person[key])` ,or it will be treated as string

```
digit_str = person[key]
# checks value only consists of digits
if digit_str.isdigit():
    # converts digits-only value to integer
    i += int(digit_str)
```

Comment: do you mean `i += int(person[key])`?